# Android XML RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I'm having a little problem with my xml.

The code below displays a textview which is always at the top and a listview below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/HF_bg">"

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/header" 
android:padding="10dp"/>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="@dimen/HF_headerText"
android:textColor="@color/HF_headerText"
android:background="@color/HF_headerbg"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whats I'm trying to do is replace the listview with a LinearLayout and display this:

```
  <LinearLayout 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/HF_contentbg"
      android:padding="5dp">

      <TextView android:textStyle="bold" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/JD_description"/>

      <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   

     <TextView android:textStyle="bold" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/JD_address"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/address"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <TextView android:id="@+id/postcode"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: So what happened when you tried?  What's your question?

Comment: So whats the problem, what problem you are facing in replacing?

Comment: I tried removing the listview completely and replacing it with the linearlayout above. What happens is the Textview stays at the top of the screen as I would like it but the linearlayout is beneath it, instead of below. If that makes sense?

Comment: See my answer: you forgot to put the LinearLayout **below** the TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the ListView, remove it and put the LinearLayout in its place.
Then, as per your ListView, add these two lines to your LinearLayout;

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
```

It works so, but this isn't a best practice, however.

In facts, you should dectare the TextView FIRST, and in the LinearLayout (declared AFTER) you'd have to remove the + sign from the below attribute, to be correct.

Because @+id CREATES a new id, while @id is a REFERENCE to an EXISTING one.
This is why the TextView should be declared BEFORE: to have its id EXISTING when the LinearLayout references it

Comment: That works lovely. I only thought they could be used with RelativeLayout. 
Thanks alot!

Comment: Please note a typo here: android:background="@color/HF_bg">" - there's a " that would cause trouble at the end of the line.

Comment: Erm dont really understand the second bit you put. Sorry, I'm new to Android

Comment: Just removed that "
good spot :)

Comment: The second bit just means that order matters. That's all. Each object must have a UNIQUE id to be recognized by the other components. And IDs should be defined BEFORE referencing them. Easy. ;)